# mail server receiving email from remote telnet session but not from gmail

Tags: postfix

I successfully sent mail via telnet port 25 from my local machine to my remote server running postfix/dovecot. The email successfully landed in the user's mailbox on the machine.

However, when trying to send a mail to the same user using gmail, there is no trace of the email.

main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = example.com
mydomain = example.com
mydestination = $myhostname, ip-173-31-0-112.ec2.internal, localhost.ec2.internal, localhost, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

the mail server is at mail.theomnihealthgroup.com. The telnet session is here:

```
Trying 3.95.150.105...
Connected to mail.theomnihealthgroup.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.theomnihealthgroup.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
ehlo mail.theomnihealthgroup.com
250-mail.theomnihealthgroup.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
mail from: mygmailaccount@gmail.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: pete4@theomnihealthgroup.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
subject: check it

awesome
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B03C9802BF
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host
```

Comment: OK, I have added the requested information to the end of the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MX record is incorrect.

```
$ host -t mx theomnihealthgroup.com
theomnihealthgroup.com mail is handled by 1 mail.
```

But your mail server is at `mail.theomnihealthgroup.com`.

Edit your DNS MX record to correct this.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm using godaddy's dns which I'm not used to. I have an A record for host mail with the name fiel set to "mail" and the a value set to X.XX.XXX.XXX. Then I have an MX record with name "@" and a value set to "mail". Not sure why this wrong.

Comment: @StevieD A MX record value "mail" is not a fully qualified domain name. It's interpreted literally, as you can see above. It must be the fully qualified domain name.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll give it a shot. When I do this in a bind zone record, I have this: "@ IN  MX  5 mail". I was using that as a reference.

Comment: @StevieD That's valid in a BIND zone, as it will just append the ORIGIN. It's not valid in GoDaddy's crappy web interface. Anyway, I can see the MX record is correct now.

Comment: OK, looks like setting MX record to fqdn did the trick. Mail was received. I guess I can just trash the A record for "mail".

Comment: @StevieD No, you need that! How else will anyone find the IP address of the mail server?

Comment: Heh, yeah. Getting very late. Brain is fried.